# Storing Dynamic WTForms Data to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have a Flask app for project management that queries a question bank, then creates a dynamic WTForms object (as per the [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/specific_problems/?highlight=dynamic#dynamic-form-composition)). My question is what to do from there. I have a SQLAlchemy table with elements that are going to be required for all projects (name, status, type, etc.), but the dynamically created bits from the dynamic are going to vary a bunch because the questions are all user generated (and stored in a different SQLAlchemy table), so hard-coding the questions into the project table doesn't make sense.

I've tried using `setattr()` to store the data with the project, but that doesn't work because the data doesn't persist after a new page request.

I've also tried doing a SQLAlchemy query update with a dictionary from the WTForms data, but it just tells me that the column for the first question doesn't exist.

Anyone have a clever idea for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a third table of Project Attributes (many to one to both the Project and Question) to store the answers in. It makes my database relations pretty convoluted, but it works!